# Fit data in Python (sine wave?)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-fitting

I have data which I would like to visualise. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize 
import curve_fit

xdata = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])   
ydata = np.array([26.2, 27.2, 27.9, 27.9, 27.2, 26.2, 25.3, 24.5, 24.2, 24.4, 24.7, 25.4])

def func(x, p1,p2,p3):
    return p1 + p3*np.sin(p2*x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=(25.931, 0.5629,1.8978))  

import matplotlib.pylab as plt   
plt.plot(xdata, ydata,'o')   
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]),linewidth=2, color = 'red')   
plt.show()
```

I am unhappy with the result. How can I get a better fit? Does the function I define need to be more complex? Do I need a completely different approach, another method?

I also tried this approach:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d  
f = interp1d(xdata, ydata, kind='cubic')  
xnew = np.linspace(0, 11, num=100, endpoint=True)  
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', color = 'blue')
```

The result looks much nicer.
I am searching for a fitting method which gives a similar result when plotted. I am sorry for being unable to express it clearer. That's probably already part of the problem :(

Comment: What are you unhappy about? How do you expect us to guess?

Comment: the return statement of your `func` should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, `np.polyfit()` gave the desired result:

```
z = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 6)
f = np.poly1d(z)

x_new = np.linspace(xdata[0], xdata[-1], 150)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'o', x_new, y_new)
```

I guess, the biggest part of my problem was the wrong assumption that my data is like a sine wave...